# Pass all environment variables to sudo'ed script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

I have one shell script that calls another using sudo, e.g:
test1.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "In test1"
UVAR=bar
echo "UVAR=${UVAR}"
sudo ./test2.sh
echo "In test1 - after call to test2"
echo "UVAR=${UVAR}"
```

and test2.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo "In test2"
whoami
echo "UVAR=${UVAR}"
UVAR=baz
echo "UVAR=${UVAR}"
echo "leaving test2"
```

I can make single variables from `test1.sh` (e.g. `UVAR`) available in `test2.sh` by putting `UVAR=$UVAR` in front of the call to `sudo`, but what if I want it to be for *all* variables? Explicitly naming all variables in the call to `test2.sh` becomes unpractical (especially as I don't have direct control over which variables might be present in practice). If I didn't call `test2.sh` with `sudo` (it's needed in the real problem) I could just source `test2.sh`.

An extra bonus is a way that allows me to protect `test1.sh` against changes to the variables made in `test2.sh`, i.e. in the example the second line outputting `UVAR` in `test1.sh` should give the same result as the first.

(I'm tagging this with bash, as the scripts use bash at the moment, but if it can be solved with some other shell, I'll be interested to know, and if only minor changes to the scripts are required could consider replacing bash with something else)

Comment: `/bin/sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: You have to export `UVAR` et al, you need to use the `-E` with `sudo` to preserve the environment, *and* `sudo` has to be configured to *allow* you to preserve your environment.

Comment: @Cyrus: Right, that might be a little confusing because I didn't think about that when I wrote my example scripts. The real first script actually has `#!/bin/bash`, and the possible second scripts use either `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` which is actually dash on the machine whether this is supposed to run. I don't think that changes anything, but sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @chepner: Actually `sudo` is called with `-E` (and (I guess, the guy who took care of that server before, set that up) configured to allow that. but having to export variables is about the same as having to mention them explicitly (i.e. undesirable).

Comment: You have three ways to pass values to another process: as command-line arguments, via the environment, or explicitly read from a file. Take your pick.

Comment: Yes, but if I didn't need sudo I could just have sourced the second script, effectively making it run in the same process, thus not having to pass the variables. I was kind of hoping for a trick that allowed that while using sudo (maybe a `susource`), but thinking about it, I want those elevated privileges than come from sudo, isolated in another process, making this essentially impossible.

Comment: Have you look at doing a typeset -p > somefile.txt and source that file with test2 ? That would give test2 the same environment including variable within test1 ... just an idea ?

Comment: I've never used `typeset`, so no, but I had thought about making a horrible loop over the output of `env` to somehow add them all to the command line invoking `test2.sh`, but it felt too horrible to explore further. I'll read a bit up on `typeset`, but that looks like just the kind of hack I was hoping for.

Comment: Child processes cannot change environment variables (or anything else) in their parents. So you don't need to worry about `UVAR`. But you shouldn't give your variables ALL-CAPS names; those are generally reserved for the shell and OS.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167334/24557) on [unix.se], if you use `zsh`, you could run the outer script as root and drop privileges for parts of it by manually setting `EUID`. That's not perfect, but it's closer than any simple solution with bash, afaik.